# How to set change the retry attempts based of the exception type in Kafka SeekToCurrentErrorHandler?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot application and i am trying to create a Kafka retry listener wherein, based of the exception type i need to change the retry attempts.

For example:

If exception type is A then the retry attempts should be 5
If exception type is B then the retry attempts should be 10

Can anyone recommend how do to this in Spring Kafka?

Following is my ListenerFactory. I am using SeekToCurrentErrorHandler

```
Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, test> retryListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, test> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
            System.out.println(
                    "RetryPolicy** limit has been exceeded! You should really handle this better." + record.key());
        }, new FixedBackOff(0L, 3L));
        errorHandler.addNotRetryableException(IllegalArgumentException.class);
        errorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        // to keep the consumers alive the failure gets reported to broker so that
        // consumers remain alive
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        factory.setConcurrency(2);
        return factory;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 2.6, you can add a function to determine the `BackOff` to use, based on the consumer record and/or exception:

```java
/**
 * Set a function to dynamically determine the {@link BackOff} to use, based on the
 * consumer record and/or exception. If null is returned, the default BackOff will be
 * used.
 * @param backOffFunction the function.
 * @since 2.6
 */
public void setBackOffFunction(BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, BackOff> backOffFunction) {
    this.failureTracker.setBackOffFunction(backOffFunction);
}
```

This is only called when there is no current `BackOff` for this record (i.e. it won't help with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708287/how-to-reset-the-retry-count-in-spring-kafka-consumer-when-the-exception-thrown/64716441#64716441)).

Comment: I opened an issue to allow resetting the failure tracker if the exception type changes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1610

Comment: Thanks alot @GaryRussell !! I have another question, is there a way i can set the no. of retry attempts with ExpoentialBackOff? My requirement is to change the no. of retries based of the exception type, and also cause a delay exponentially between each retry. Can you please suggest. For now i am doing this. errorHandler.setBackOffFunction((record,exception)-> {
    if(msg.getNewError().equals(errorCodes.getApiError()) 
     return new FixedBackOff(0L, apiRetryCount);
    else 
     return new FixedBackOff(0L, retryCount );
   
  });

Comment: You are using `FixedBackOff` with no delay between retries. Use an `ExpontialBackOff` instead - `new ExponentialBackOff(initial, multiplier)`. You can also set the max interval to add a cap to the delay between attempts, and `setMaxElapsedTime` to stop retrying (instead of a retry count) (you can calculate that based on the retry count and the other settings). 2.6.3 with the new feature will be released next week,

Comment: Thankyou. Have another question. In the recovery when all the retries are exhausted i need to put the message to error topic. can i use DealLetterPublishingRecoverer for that purpose?

Comment: Yes. That is what it is for.

Comment: Thankyou but my requirement is that once all the retries are exhausted, i need to save the record to the database... and if database is down or any exception gets thrown while saving to database then it should go to a error topic. Can you please suggest. SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
   try {
    //when all retries are exhausted save to database and if exception is thrown then put to deadletter topic
   }
   catch(Exception se) {
    //new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(getEventKafkaTemplate());
   }
  });

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it doesn't render well and is hard to read; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. Don't create a new recoverer in the `catch` block; simply define it elsewhere, say in variable `dlpr` and call `dlpr.accept(record, exception);` if the DB store fails.